# 'unlimited' bandwith / disk space shared hosting

Tags: hosting, asp.net, web-hosting

I am doing some research on ASP.NET shared hosting providers and looking to purchase a plan. So far MochaHost seems like the best deal that I could find...

I'm just wondering about some of these providers like MochaHost, GoDaddy, WebHost4Life, etc.. which offer 'unlimited' bandwith and/or disk-space plans for cheap (under 20$ a month)..

I'm guessing that these plans are a bit of 'scam' you could say, in that if you ever had enough traffic to warrant 'unlimited' diskspace / bandwith, your shared hosting slice would crash and burn anyway. Is that a pretty safe assumption? Or is there actual value in these plans?

If this is the case, perhaps I should be focusing more on finding a hosting provider that has great tools / support / performance... rather then being inticed by the 'unlimited' bandwith/disk space offering...

About how much bandwith per month would I need if I had a consumer level site? I know that's a very broad statement, but lets say I had a basic forums / social networking type software. How many users per day would I need to fill let's say a 50 GB monthly quota? Ballpark maybe? Again, realize that's a tough question to get a real answer, but maybe someone has gone through growing pains on their site before and can spit out some numbers on when they had to move to a higher bandwith cap... also, any additional opinions on hosting providers in general would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You get what you pay for....

Comment: Check out the cloud--Azure and AWS.

Answer (score 2):

I personally shy away from the true discount hosting providers, and if you are not doing anything massive with regard to images/video, your bandwidth is going to be minimal.

For example, I have a site with a forum with about 5,000 threads, blog with 200 posts, and about 700-1000 visitors a day, and it uses about 1Gb a month in bandwidth.

However, every site is different you just have to know your site and average load, or just get it out somewhere to see what the bandwidth is.

I would evaluate the host based on the reputation that they have, their speed, performance and more.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That number you gave me was exactly the ballpark figure I was looking for..

How hard is it to transfer domain names? I don't want to kill myself with 'analysis paralysis' here, especially since these plans are so cheap and I can do a month to month. So If I pick a host, and register lets say 3 domain names / private registration... How hard will it be to transfer those domains if I don't like my provider?

I just don't want to limit my creativity or features because I'm concerned about bandwith or hard-disk usage

Answer (score 0):

For high performance see [www.rackspacecloud.com](http://www.rackspacecloud.com) They allow ASP.NET on their cloud for $99 per month minnimum and it scales with you being billed for overages. They also have a calculator to see how much traffic to expect, etc...

For non-cloud hosting:
The unlimited bandwidth must be shared with all of the other sites on that pipe so it is in theory limited to the amount of traffic available at any given time. I think hosting is like anything else in that you get what you pay for.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, you need to be a little bit lucky when finding a webhosting provider, as a big player always has thousands of servers, some servers performs very good, some are not. So the most important thing comes to be their customer service.

Comment: Please do not use Serverfault to advertise your website.